# Mac Terminal: Delete Entire Column From Json File

Tags: json, terminal

How can I use mac terminal to delete an entire column from a json File.

The Json structure is as follows:

```
[{
    "recordid": "6a0a9c66f8e0292a54c9f023c93732f1b41d8943",
    "fields": {
        "city": "Cove",
        "zip": "71937",
        "dst": 1,
        "geopoint": [
            34.398483,
            -94.39398
        ],
        "longitude": -94.39398,
        "state": "AR",
        "latitude": 34.398483,
        "timezone": -6
    },
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
            -94.39398,
            34.398483
        ]
    },
    "record_timestamp": "2018-02-09T09:33:38.603-07:00"
},
{
    "recordid": "37e2c801aafc7befde9734bcb1b1f83a5645ad0f",
    "fields": {
        "city": "Edgemont",
        "zip": "72044",
        "dst": 1,
        "geopoint": [
            35.624351,
            -92.16056
        ],
        "longitude": -92.16056,
        "state": "AR",
        "latitude": 35.624351,
        "timezone": -6
    },
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
            -92.16056,
            35.624351
        ]
    },
    "record_timestamp": "2018-02-09T09:33:38.603-07:00"
}]
```

Using Terminal, how can I remove both and all columns including `geopoint` and `geometry` attributes while saving the file with the rest which I would wanna keep.

Comment: Thats invalid json!

Comment: @0stone0 Fixed....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [jq](/questions/tagged/jq), map trough the JSON, delete `.geometry` and `.fields.geopoint`;

```sh
jq 'map(del(.fields.geopoint, .geometry))'
```

Result;

```
[
  {
    "recordid": "6a0a9c66f8e0292a54c9f023c93732f1b41d8943",
    "fields": {
      "city": "Cove"
    }
  },
  {
    "recordid": "6a0a9c66f8e0292a54c9f023c93732f1b41d8342",
    "fields": {
      "city": "Edgemont"
    }
  }
]
```

```sh
cat json.json | jq 'map(del(.fields.geopoint, .geometry))' > new.json
mv new.json json.json # Overwrites original file
```

[Try it online!](https://jqplay.org/s/6zAQn6_8C3)

---

```sh
cat mainzip.json | jq 'map(del(.datasetid, .fields.city, .fields.dst, .fields.geopoint, .fields.state, .fields.timezone, .type.point, .geometry, .record_timestamp))' > temporary_mainzip.json
mv temporary_mainzip.json mainzip.json
```

Comment: I cannot copy and paste the file... It needs to be uploaded somehow....

Comment: @Zeusox You'll need the output to a local file? Please see my edit!

Comment: Do I need to install the jq library ?

Comment: @Zeusox I thought it was default installed on a mac, otherwise use `brew install jq`. Or, take a look [here](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/) for more instructions.

Comment: it is not installed within terminal...so might have to do a quick install and try...

Comment: also I tried your solution on jq online play and it did not work...

Comment: There is an link at the bottom of my answer to jqplay, it works there...

Comment: The issue is when I place this command: cat mainzip.json |jq 'map(del(.datasetid, .fields.city, .fields.dst, .fields.geopoint, .fields.state, .fields.timezone, .type.point, .geometry, .record_timestamp))'

It does show the desired output being processed but when I go back to my json file I find the same results as before though...

Comment: The command is not complete, you'll need to redirect the `jq` output to a tmp file, `jq... > mainzip.json` and then override the original json file: `mv new.json json.json`. This is also included in my answer......

Comment: yes but then it says could not find file named mv...it does not see that as move instead...

Comment: Then you probably have a quoting error since `mv` should be available as an command

Comment: I am using this command to just override the actual file:

cat mainzip.json  | jq 'map(del(.datasetid, .fields.city, .fields.dst, .fields.geopoint, .fields.state, .fields.timezone, .type.point, .geometry, .record_timestamp))'

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is going to be the 3 time i'll say this.... Your still missing the `> file` part in the command. Please take a look [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/420981/how-do-i-save-terminal-output-to-a-file) to understand `>`. PLease see my answer, i''ll add your command.